# utf8_encoding for hebrew text

Tags: php, json, utf-8, hebrew

I need to put an array with some Hebrew text through a JSON encoder, the array on it one gets

```
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

while I did have success passing the array with using utf8_encode to the data in Hebrew, the text turned into

××¤××¨ ×××¨×× - ××¤× ×× ×"×.
××× ××¨×§ - ×ª×§×©××¨×ª.
×¢××××, ××¨× - ×××××¨××ª.
××¢×¨××ª ×¨××©××××ª

from

אפאר טבריה - אפי מנכ"ל.
אלי ברק - תקשורת.
עליזה, ורד - מזכירות.
מערכת רישומית

```
//$data["rawVals"]["Other"]= utf8_encode($data["rawVals"]["Other"]);
//$data["vals"]["Other"]= utf8_encode($data["vals"]["Other"]);
$rJSON = my_json_encode( $data );
return $returnPlainJSON ? $rJSON : runner_htmlspecialchars( $rJSON );
```

well, what should I do to make the text readable and also pass through the encoder?

Comment: What does `my_json_encode` do?

Comment: What encoding is your data currently stored in, if you think encoding it _to_ UTF-8 would be the solution? Is your whole website/app using a _different_ encoding than UTF-8 to begin with? Then _that’s_ what you should fix.

Comment: function my_json_encode($value){
  return json_encode($value);
    }

Comment: I am using utf-8 on my app, the data is stored at mysql encoded with utf8_unicode_ci
all i need is to pass the array through the encoder successfully
wich dosent work as is..